# pip not installing gym_super_mario_bros

Tags: python

Which part of the process is causing the issue on Windows, Python 3.9 and Spyder IDE, starting a new project "[Play Super Mario Bros with a Double Deep Q-Network](https://blog.paperspace.com/building-double-deep-q-network-super-mario-bros/)"? I'm trying 
[`pip install gym_super_mario_bros`](https://pypi.org/project/gym-super-mario-bros/):

```
pip install gym_super_mario_bros
Collecting gym_super_mario_bros
  Using cached gym_super_mario_bros-7.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (199 kB)
Collecting nes-py>=8.1.4
  Using cached nes_py-8.2.1.tar.gz (77 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: gym>=0.17.2 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (1.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.5.21,>=1.4.0 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (1.5.21)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.48.2 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (4.65.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=1.2.0 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from gym>=0.17.2->nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.8.0 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from gym>=0.17.2->nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (4.11.4)
Requirement already satisfied: gym-notices>=0.0.4 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from gym>=0.17.2->nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (0.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.8.0->gym>=0.17.2->nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\peace\.conda\envs\v1\lib\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.48.2->nes-py>=8.1.4->gym_super_mario_bros) (0.4.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: nes-py
  Building wheel for nes-py (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for nes-py (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for nes-py
Failed to build nes-py
Installing collected packages: nes-py, gym-super-mario-bros
    Running setup.py install for nes-py: started
    Running setup.py install for nes-py: finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\peace\.conda\envs\V1\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\peace\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u43ijtl9\\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\peace\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u43ijtl9\\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\peace\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-d69oggpg'
       cwd: C:\Users\peace\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u43ijtl9\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\
  Complete output (21 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
  copying nes_py\nes_env.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
  copying nes_py\_image_viewer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
  copying nes_py\_rom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
  copying nes_py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\play_human.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\play_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
  copying nes_py\app\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\wrappers
  copying nes_py\wrappers\joypad_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\wrappers
  copying nes_py\wrappers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\wrappers
  running build_ext
  building 'nes_py.lib_nes_env' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for nes-py
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\peace\.conda\envs\V1\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\peace\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u43ijtl9\\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\peace\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u43ijtl9\\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\peace\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-a0t4fw7o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\peace\.conda\envs\V1\Include\nes-py'
         cwd: C:\Users\peace\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u43ijtl9\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    C:\Users\peace\.conda\envs\V1\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
    copying nes_py\nes_env.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
    copying nes_py\_image_viewer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
    copying nes_py\_rom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
    copying nes_py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
    copying nes_py\app\cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
    copying nes_py\app\play_human.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
    copying nes_py\app\play_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
    copying nes_py\app\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\app
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\wrappers
    copying nes_py\wrappers\joypad_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\wrappers
    copying nes_py\wrappers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\nes_py\wrappers
    running build_ext
    building 'nes_py.lib_nes_env' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\peace\.conda\envs\V1\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\peace\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u43ijtl9\\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\peace\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u43ijtl9\\nes-py_170cea2fe9814c38bebc32cfaaab14ed\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\peace\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-a0t4fw7o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\peace\.conda\envs\V1\Include\nes-py' Check the logs for full command output.
```

When I run below code two times import worked:

```
if name in sys.modules:
    print(f"{name!r} already in sys.modules")
elif (spec := importlib.util.find_spec(name)) is not None:
    # If you choose to perform the actual import ...
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    print(f"{name!r} has been imported")
else:
    print(f"can't find the {name!r} module")
if name in sys.modules:
    print(f"{name!r} already in sys.modules")
elif (spec := importlib.util.find_spec(name)) is not None:
    # If you choose to perform the actual import ...
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    print(f"{name!r} has been imported")
else:
    print(f"can't find the {name!r} module")
```

But then ran into issues:

```
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-1-1-v0')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\peace\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18864\2763352391.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-1-1-v0')

AttributeError: module 'gym_super_mario_bros' has no attribute 'make'
```

I don't know if import worked and why I can't run the module.

Comment: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Comment: Note, the correct command for pip is: `pip install gym-super-mario-bros` and not `pip install gym_super_mario_bros`.